# Update column based on matching values in other table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, match

I have two tables calendar and customer table. Calendar table have a "customer" column which has customer table "ID" as value. But unfortunately, this calendar customer field value was wrongly populated with other values. Both tables have these common fields Date, SeatingID and BusID. How to update the calendar table customer field based on these common fields?.

Below is the structure of both tables.

Customer Table
[image]

calendar Table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update calendar ca left join customer c 
on c.DateofTravel=ca.Date and c.SeatingID=ca.SeatingID and c.BusID=ca.BusID 
set 
ca.Customer=c.ID;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can `UPDATE` the `Customer` field of the second table `Calendar` from the first table `Customer` by `JOIN`ing the two tables like so:

```
UPDATE calendar c1
INNER JOIN Customer c2 ON c1.SeatingID = c2.SeatingID AND c1.BusID = c2.BusID
SET c1.Customer = c2.ID --or SET c1.Customer = c2.PassengerName or whatever you want.
```

In the `SET` clause, you can set the column you wish to update, and you can also `JOIN` the two tables based on any predicate, I used `c1.SeatingID = c2.SeatingID AND c1.BusID = c2.BusID`, but you can choose what is suitable for your needs.

### [Here is a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50681/1)

Comment: I tried this using all joins but the data filtered is incorrect. updating only less number of columns although there are more matching records..

Comment: @Uma, How the data filtered is incorrect? and what is the problem in my query? can you please explain further. You have to define the condition join propelry, may be you need to add more predicate if you have more than one matched column. Can you please set up a demo explaining the problem in SQL fiddle, or edit my [Demo query ON SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50681/1) with this incorrect results and what is the correct results you want to get from this query. Thanks

Comment: update calendar ca left join customer c 
on c.DateofTravel=ca.Date and c.SeatingID=ca.SeatingID and c.BusID=ca.BusID 
set 
ca.Customer=c.ID;

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
UPDATE calendar cal, customer cust 
SET cal.Customer = cust.ID
where cal.SeatingID = cust.SeatingID 
and cal.BusID = cust.BusID
and cal.DATE = cust.DateOfTravel;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60757/2/0) DEMO

[Here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/) is link to more informations abaout `update`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query it will help you to updated table column from another table column:

```
UPDATE tableName1 AS tb1
INNER JOIN tableName2 AS tb2 
ON (tb1.columnName= tb2.columnName) 
SET tb1.updatedColumn = tb2.updatedColumnValue
WHERE ADD HERE CONDITION IF REQUIRED
```