# Update Email Matching Between 2 Tables in MySQL - BLACKLIST

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sql-update

Here's a common task any database administrator needs to have. It's a simple blacklist.  I have 2 tables with the field 'email' in common.  What I want to do is set the active=0 on the 2nd table if the email matches on the first table.

here's pseudo code

i.e. update users set active =0 (on first table) where email on table 2 matches email on table 1

What's the most elegant way to do this?

Table 1 name = 'users'
Table 2 name = 'blacklist'

Here's the updated script.  I was able to author the correct answer based on the responses.  The responses was updating table 2 not table 1 - i.e. the reverse.

Here's the finished script...

```
update users u
inner join blacklist b on u.email=b.email
set u.active=0 ;
```

There's a similar post to this that gives the answer, however it isn't immediately apparent how to do this with the answer they give. see....

[Update column based on matching values in other table in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650575/update-column-based-on-matching-values-in-other-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
update users u
inner join users_blacklist b on b.email = u.email
set u.active = 0
```

This query works by `join`ing both tables on their `email` column, and updating only the records that matched.

This assumes that:

- `users` is the table to update, while `users_blacklist` is the blacklist table
- `email` is a unique key in the blacklist table