# update SQL statement if only exist a record in a table

Tags: mysql, node.js, lamp

Can I change following SQL statement if there exist a matching record in my table else do nothing

```
UPDATE todos SET status = 'done' WHERE todo_id = ?
```

I tried various ways but it doesn't work

Comment: What you mean? If no row matches the condition, nothing will be changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update column based on matching values in other table in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650575/update-column-based-on-matching-values-in-other-table-in-mysql)

Comment: your query is perfectly fine, it will do nothing when no matching todo_id is found